# ODBC SQLParamData return data

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, odbc

I am trying to insert o blob in  a database. I have succeed to enter data i two columns.

I am having problem whit SQLParamData .It returns an error when it should return SQL_NEED_DATA(i will post code)

When i run SQLGetDiagRec it returns S1010 with error text Function sequence error .
I search this error on the internet and i learned that it could be related to a parameter from SQLBindParameter .

```
// Bind the parameter marker.
    retCode = retcode = SQLBindParameter(hstmt,  // hstmt
         1,                     // ipar
         SQL_PARAM_INPUT,            // fParamType
         SQL_C_BINARY,               // fCType
         SQL_LONGVARBINARY,           // FSqlType
         lbytes,                  // cbColDef
         0,                     // ibScale
         &pParmID,       // rgbValue
         0,                     // cbValueMax
         &cbTextSize);            // pcbValue

    SqlError(hstmt,SQL_HANDLE_STMT,_T("WriteBlob"), _T("CTLSqlConnection"), _T("SQLBindParameter"));
    if(retCode != SQL_SUCCESS)
    {
        delete pData;

        if(!EndTransaction(FALSE))
            return ERR_ENDTRANSACTION_FAILED;
        else
            return -3;
    }

    //SQLExec
    retcode = retCode = SQLExecDirect(hstmt,(SQLTCHAR*)szSqlStat, SQL_NTS);

        SQLRETURN ret;
        SQLCHAR* SQLState;
        SQLINTEGER NativeError;
        SQLSMALLINT errmsglen;
        SQLCHAR errmsg[255];
        SQLCHAR errstate[50];



    retCode = SQLParamData(hstmt, &pParmID);

SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, 1, (SQLCHAR*)errstate, &NativeError, (SQLCHAR*)errmsg, sizeof(errmsg), &errmsglen);
    if(retCode == SQL_NEED_DATA)
    {
        // Put final batch.
        SQLPutData(hstmt, pData, lbytes); 
    }
    else
    {
        delete pData;
```

If this part of the code is not relevant enough i will post more.

Hope you can help me .Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic looks wrong here. It is when SQLExecute (SQLExecDirect) returns SQL_NEED_DATA you call SQLParamData and it tells you will parameter you need to supply data for with SQLPutData. If you call SQLParamData when SQLExecute did not return SQL_NEED_DATA I can well imagine it is a function sequence error. I could probably dig you out an example from somewhere if you still need it.

Comment: Thanks.It would be really helpful if you could give me an example.Thanks again .

Comment: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MJEVANS/DBD-ODBC-1.40_2/dbdimp.c search for SQL_ParamData. It basically calls SQLExecute or SQLExecDirect and IF SQL_NEED_DATA is returned it calls SQLParamData to find out which bound parameter is required then calls SQLPutData to send the parameter.